# Webmaster Tools "Fetch as Google" doesn't fetch my js/css/images on a CDN

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, fetch-as-google

I've discovered that when I do Google Webmaster Tools --> Fetch as Google on a page on my site (let's call it http://example.com), it shows the static assets (js, css, and images) as **Temporarily unreachable**.

My static assets are behind an Amazon CloudFront CDN distribution, with the origin being my site, http://example.com. I have CNAMEd the CloudFront to **assets.example.com**.

That's exactly what is showing as "Temporarily unreachable" - all the css and js hosted at assets.example.com (for example *assets.example.com/assets/application.css*). The thing is, I can reach all those files just fine. I fear that googlebot is not seeing the js and css of my site, since when I do a **Fetch and Render** it says "This is how Googlebot saw the page:" and sure enough it's the page as it would look with no css or js.

I went through the responses on [this somewhat similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78622/google-doesnt-crawl-cdn-files), but my CloudFront distribution doesn't even have a robots.txt that could be blocking anything, and the response headers when I do a `curl -I` on my css & js don't show anything alarming.

What could be causing googlebot to say that my static assets are **Temporarily unreachable**? Thanks!

Comment: Does your _main site_ have a robots.txt file? The answer(s) on that other question seem to suggest that CF reads the robots.txt on your main site and serves that - although I think I may have misunderstood something??!

Comment: @w3d Yes definitely, main site has a normal robots.txt file. I have CloudFront set up such that it can *only* access anything in the assets/* directory, as to not duplicate all pages of my site with the assets.example.com URL.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it!

My **assets.example.com** CloudFront distribution needed a robots.txt file after all. After adding one following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579386/1231503), googlebot is able to fetch & render my static assets successfully.

It no longer reports them as Temporarily unreachable, and instead shows Complete.