# URL crawlable in old Google search console, but blocked in new

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, crawl-errors

Google stopped crawling images for our site, when we moved images to cdn subdomain.

Old search console states image is crawlable, but new one states it is blocked by robots.txt (for same link).

our robots.txt has only this:

```
User-agent: *
```

Anyone know why is that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which robots.txt file did you post?  Is that the one from the main site, or the one from the subdomain?

Comment: One from the subdomain.

Comment: Have you tried a second line with just `Disallow:` in that robots.txt file?   That is the standard way to allow all crawling.   A missing robots.txt file should also allow all crawling.  I think a blank robots.txt, or a robots.txt with just a `User-Agent` line it it should also, but I'd go with one of the standard ways just to make sure.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't then be blocked on both consoles?

Comment: I'm really not sure what is going on.   That is the only possible thing that I'm coming up with and I don't have a lot of hope that it would actually fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I tried, but it did not help.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a virtual robots.txt on the subdomain. Check with your CDN provider to see if perhaps there's a setting you can toggle to allow crawling.

Comment: How do you mean virtual robots.txt ? I am using cloudflare

Comment: Related, could be helpful: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/robots-txt-fetch-failed-by-google-webmasters/2417/11 --- I'm with @WebElaine, it's almost certainly a CDN setting. At one point I was dealing with a robots.txt issue for a domain on Fastly, things got complex pretty quickly. Work with Cloudfare to resolve this.

Comment: I will give it a try, but when I emulate googlebot user agent, or use old console it works just fine. Thanks

Comment: The URL Inspection tool is designed to check html pages and not resources like images. It's known to show that misleading error for images. Your best move is to search for your images in Google image search and see if they are there. Do a site:example.com search

Comment: @tony mcreath same images are being blocked in preview page tool, while ones not from subdomain work just fine

Comment: Have you checked for a `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` getting served with the images?  I check with the command line `curl --head http://cdn.example.com/image.jpg`

Comment: No such tag in headers Stephen

Comment: See also: [Google doesn't crawl CDN files](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78622/google-doesnt-crawl-cdn-files)

Comment: Is this a HTML document that you are testing, or some other type like an image?